# Setting GitLab environmental variable via a bash command

Tags: bash, yaml, gitlab

So. I'm using GitLab and in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have the following:

```
variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME | tr / -
```

The `$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME` basically reads the branch name, in my case `development/karl`. I'm trying to set the variable name `CONTAINER_NAME` to `development-karl` though.

It doesn't seem to be working as when I echo the variable, the following shows:

```
$ echo $CONTAINER_NAME
development/karl | tr / -
```

I was expecting:

```
$ echo $CONTAINER_NAME
development-karl
```

I've also tried:

```
variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: $( echo "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" | tr / - )
    CONTAINER_NAME_2: $( tr / - <<<"$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" )
    CONTAINER_NAME_3: "${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME////-}"

//.. more script stuff

script:
  - echo $CONTAINER_NAME
  - echo $CONTAINER_NAME_2
  - echo $CONTAINER_NAME_3
```

And got:

```
Successfully extracted cache
$ echo $CONTAINER_NAME
( echo "development/karl" | tr / - )
$ echo $CONTAINER_NAME_2
( tr / - <<<"development/karl" )
$ echo $CONTAINER_NAME_3

$ npm install
```

Comment: @Inian I'm testing it, the builder is super slow so it will take awhile lol

Comment: Did the solution help solve your problem?

Comment: @Inian Updated question with your suggestions, doesn't seem to work. I think I have to use the command-substitution syntax in the `- script` area and not up by the variables.

Comment: I guess you are missing something here, don't think  your `.yml` supports shell syntaxes, I have deleted mine.

Comment: @Inian That's what I suspect!